# Symfony 2 performance issues

Tags: php, sql, symfony

Well, average execution time on my website is about 5 seconds, which is a lot. But what's strange is that the execution time of one of my routes exceeds 30 seconds and throws the error! The website is already on the server, so I can't change php.ini or add any accelerators. On local server the speed was about the same.

I'm using app_dev.php without the profiler, but app.php doesn't make it any faster.

I'm using doctrine ORM, and the route executing 30 seconds contains a query with ~10 left joins. But the tables contain only like 20k records, and all these tables are well optimised, so...

I also use `knp-paginator-bundle`. Doesn't it make the query execute twice?

Answer (score 1):

The following resource is very useful [High Performance Websites with Symfony2](http://slides.seld.be/?file=2011-10-20%20High%20Performance%20Websites%20with%20Symfony2.html).

One of Jordi's recommendation about performance is:

> Don't rush things Figure out the root cause first

While this is true, **you should figure out the bottlenecks and address them**, there are some basic things you should do when you deploy a Symfony2 application to a production server that will help you improve performance (form the Symfony2 documentation [How to Deploy a Symfony2 Application](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/tools.html)):

> 1. Upload your modified code to the live server;
> 2. Update your vendor dependencies (typically done via Composer, and may be done before uploading);
> 3. Running database migrations or similar tasks to update any changed data structures;
> 4. Clearing (and perhaps more importantly, warming up) your cache.

For step 2 make sure you use the `--no-debug` and `--optimize-autoloader` flags:

```
php composer.phar install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader
```

For step 4 use `--env=prod` and the flag `--no-debug`:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

In addition to basic deployment procedures you may find that enabling doctrine metadata, query and result cache a source of performance improvement:

```
# app/config/config_prod.yml
doctrine:
    orm:
        metadata_cache_driver: apc
        result_cache_driver:   apc
        query_cache_driver:    apc
```

See [Doctrine Cache](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/caching.html), [Improve Doctrine performance up to 100% on your Symfony2 project](https://coderwall.com/p/ry1y0a) and [DoctrineBundle Configuration (Caching Drivers)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#caching-drivers) for additional information.

In a different note, a query with 10 left joins sounds like a red flag to me. I would check out the logic of the code and the need for such a query in your application.

As a final word of advice (and this is beyond the answer to the question) use the latest versions of PHP. After we updated from PHP 5.3.10 to PHP 5.5.9 load times where cut in half for our application.

Good luck!

Additional resources:

- [Symfony2 Performance](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/performance.html)

Comment: The OP says: `can't change php.ini or add any accelerators`

Comment: Are you on shared hosting? Can you execute commands like composer or symfony commands? For caching you are not required to use APC, this is just a driver, you can setup a memcached server and use it as your caching system. It is highly recommended that you install APC or similar accelerator as it will improve the performance of your application (unless you are running on php 5.5 which includes Zend OPCache).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't use app_dev.php on your production machine. By default it starts the kernel with debugging enabled, giving potential attackers useful informations about your system.

About your performance problem: Install xdebug on your local machine, and enable the profiler in Symfony2. If your script runs into a timeout, increase the execution time in your php.ini.

The timeline in the profiler should give you useful information about potential time sinks in your application.

If you need more detailed timings, you can use the stopwatch service inside your controller or service and measure whatever you want.

Inside a controller it would look like this:

```
$stopwatch = $this->get('debug.stopwatch');
$stopwatch->start("someEvent");
// Here is the code you want to measure
$stopwatch->stop("someEvent");
```

If you want to use the stopwatch service inside another service, you can simply inject it. However, the stopwatch service is only available in debug mode, so you should use "on-invalid" in your service definition:

```
<service id=...>
     <argument type="service" id="debug.stopwatch" on-invalid="null" />
</service>
```

Inside your service make sure that the stopwatch service was properly injected before accessing it.